# Django Formset Order on Template Render after Errors

Tags: django, django-templates, render, formset

I have a formset that adds new forms by javascript in diferent order in the page. someones in the bigining and others in the end. But when i save, the errors are shows in order of form-n form-n+1, etc.  no in the order that i put in the hiddenfield form-N-ORDER.

how i cant show in template ordered forms by the form-N-ORDER? because in the view, i cant use:

`for form in formset.ordered_forms:`

but ordered_forms not work in template.

[image: image that shows problem on form]

this is the problem:

[image: image that shows code of error in DOM]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very unclear, can you please reword it and also show some relevant code? See how to write a [mre]